# Run functional test task to use multiple cores during build

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I know msbuild runs single threaded, but performance wise: can functional/unit tests run on multiple cores to improve performance? we have like 2700 unit tests in our test run and we are searching for ways to improve performance (.net c# build).

We have already split the test run into slow running and long running tests to make test distribution with "distribute test" faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no this build-in feature or setting in TFS test task for now. You can give a try with the method in *Jesse Houwing*'s blog [Enable parallel execution of tests using the Visual Studio Test Runner 2015.1](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2015/11/enable-parallel-execution-of-tests.html)

To get the benefits, add the following snippet to your .runsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Add this line, default is 1, which makes it run single threaded -->
    <!-- 0 will use all available cores -->
<MaxCpuCount>8</MaxCpuCount>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```